# Polars - AttributeError: 'ArrowExtensionArray' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I am trying to push dates to the SQLite database using Polars' `write_database` method:

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import date
import sqlite3

dates_dt = [date(2000, 1, 1), date(2000, 1, 2), date(2000, 1, 3)]
df = pl.DataFrame({"date": dates_dt})

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
df.write_database("test_table", "sqlite:///test.db", if_table_exists="replace")
conn.close()
```

However, I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ArrowExtensionArray' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'
```

The same problem occurs if date strings are converted to a Date column:

```py
date_str = ["2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03"]
df = pl.DataFrame({"date": date_str})
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("date").str.to_date("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in the `pd.to_pandas` function which was fixed since the pandas 2.1.0 version. Polars throws an error when writing a date or date time object if the pandas' version is not up-to-date.

Therefore, the version needs to be updated:

```bash
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Verify that the version is greater than 2.1.0 with the `pip list | grep pandas` command.

References:

- Related issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/51859
- [pd.to_pydatetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_pydatetime.html) deprecation documentation